# What do all the markings in vim `:imap` outputs mean?

Tags: vim

e.g. if I type `:im` it outputs a long list of messages of the insert mode mappings.

```
i  <Plug>(fzf-maps-i) * <C-O>:call fzf#vim#maps('i', 0)<CR>
```

The `i` is for insert mode.

`:help <Plug>` says that you use it for "internal mappings which is not to be matched with any key sequence". What is this good for? If you manage to press an unpressable key combination it will open the `:Maps` terminal buffer? Aside from this specific situation, why would you want to bind an unpressable binding?

Next, we have the `*`. What does it refer to? `:helpgrep star` or `:helpgrep *` fail me.

Next we have this line:

```
i  <Plug>(fzf-complete-file-ag) * fzf#vim#complete#path('ag -l -g ""')
```

Why does the first line above use `*` and then still use `<C-O>:call ... <CR>` while this one just mentions the function name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `<Plug>` [...] What is this good for? If you manage to press an unpressable key combination it will open the `:Maps` terminal buffer?

It is an unpressable key combination. It doesn't mean it cannot be generated. If you look at the docs of fzf.vim, you will see an example of a related mapping that user can insert into their `.vimrc`:

```
nmap <leader><tab> <plug>(fzf-maps-n)
```

If the user then presses <kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will generate `<plug>(fzf-maps-n)`. This mapping is not `noremap`, so it will trigger the `map <plug>(fzf-maps-n)` mapping defined by the plugin. This way the plugin exposes a mappable key sequence, but without any side-effects for the users where they might accidentally trigger it; though they can still map to it if they wish to.

> Next, we have the `*`

`:help map-listing` will tell you `*` means it is not remappable (i.e. created by `inoremap` instead of `imap`).

> Why does the first line above use `*` and then still use `<C-O>:call ... <CR>` while this one just mentions the function name?

It is not visible from the listing, but the command that created it was:

```
inoremap <expr> <plug>(fzf-complete-file-ag)     fzf#vim#complete#path('ag -l -g ""')
```

Note the `<expr>` modifier. `:help :map-<expr>`